# File syncing app that would sync files open with a read lock?

Tags: windows, dropbox

Used DropBox for this purpose for a while, but now it refuses to sync an sqlite database which is open using a shared lock. Are there any good alternatives?

Tried Live Mesh, Sugar Sync, PowerFolder, GoodSync and SpiderOak. SpiderOak looked most [promising](https://spideroak.com/faq/does_spideroak_backup_open_files), but for some reason doesn't synchronize at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read lock is used specifically to prevent this. If an app has a lock on a file, it explicitly wants to prevent other programs from accessing the file, probably because it is right now modifying it. (Unless of course the app itself is faulty and just lazily keeps a lock on its files even though it is not using them. In that case: use a different app)

Hence, no app in its right mind would try to read read-locked files.

Comment: But this is a read lock, not write lock! I can overwrite the file in Explorer without any problem.

Comment: And unfortunately I can't use another app, because I'm the author of it. But closing the connection to SQlite didn't solve the issue, for some reason the CloseHandle function which SQLite calls doesn't always release the lock obtained by CreateFile.

Comment: Ask how to do that on stackoverflow then. If you lock a file, you explicitly prevent other programs from accessing it.